# How do I create a for-loop where the variable's value is equal to the stop value of range when the loop runs to the end in Python?

Tags: python

I'm having a conceptual problem porting this from C to Python:

```
int p;
for (p = 32; p < 64; p += 2) {
    if (some condition)
        break;
    do some stuff
}
return p;
```

Converting the loop to `for p in range(32,64,2)` does not work.  This is because after the loop ends, `p` is equal 62 instead of 64.

I can do it with a `while` loop easily:

```
p = 32
while p < 64:
    if (some condition):
        break
    do some stuff
    p += 2
return p
```

But I'm looking for a **Pythonic way**.

Comment: "_p is equal 62 instead of 64_" - I'm not sure how is your C code ever suppose to hit the 64 when you have `<64`

Comment: @MrGrj: It doesn't. But after the loop, `p == 64`!!!

Comment: @MrGrj In C, the value of `p` is incremented, *then* the condition is tested. If the condition fails, the value isn't "rolled back" to the previous value. In Python, the assignment occurs *after* `range` as returned a in-range value, so effectively the condition is checked *before* the assignment.

Comment: There's an argument to be made that your `while` loop *is* the most Pythonic; it makes explicit the fact that `p` is not just used inside the loop, but after as well.

Comment: @chepner I would even say that the C implementation is slightly obscured as it is not directly obvious what the returned value of p would be. The Python version in that respect is much more direct.

Comment: @nluigi Indeed; usually, you use a block-local variable as the index and don't have to think about the order of events.

Comment: I agree that using `while` might be the best available choice. If there's anything significantly better than that (and there might not be), it would be reexamining why you need to be so fiddly with `p` in the first place, and accomplish your larger goal in a different way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can use `else` for `for` loop in case condition isn't met to add 2 like C loop does:

```
for p in range(32, 64, 2):
   if some_condition:
       break
else:
    # only executed if for loop iterates to the end
    p += 2
```

Comment: But does it work when I have other stuff that I'm doing after the `if` (and inside the `for`)?

Comment: of course. it enters else only if break (or return) isn't met

Comment: Your C -for- p=64 case is never going to reach the if statement

Answer (score 10):

Extend the range, but include a second "redundant" break condition.

```
for p in range(32, 65, 2):
    if p >= 64 or (some condition):
        break
    # do stuff
```

(The only significant difference between this and [Jean-François Fabre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129213/1126841) is which piece of the logic you duplicate: testing if `p` is out of range, or incrementing `p`.)

Answer (score 4):

A variation of [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129398/179715) that avoids duplicating the test would be to use `itertools.count`:

```
import itertools

for p in itertools.count(32, 2):
    if p >= 64 or (some condition):
        break
    do some stuff
return p
```

although I think that might as well be:

```
p = 32
while True:
    if p >= 64 or (some condition):
        break
    do some stuff
    p += 2
return p
```

and as tobias_k pointed out, then is trivially transformed to:

```
p = 32
while p < 64 and not (some condition):
    do some stuff
    p += 2
return p
```

which I personally think is clearer.

Comment: Why not save two lines and do `while p < 64 and not (some condition):`?

Comment: Your second version is missing a `p=32` at the start.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Oops.  Fixed.