# Does "for / range" consume a lot of memory when the range is large?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, memory

My concern is with regards to something like:

```
for i in range(1000000000):
    ...
```

From a naive point of view, I assume that an array of 1000000000 integers is allocated and initialized before the loop begins, and deallocated only after the loop ends.

So I am wondering whether or not I should replace it with:

```
i = 0
while i < 1000000000:
    ...
    i += 1
```

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/869347), a `for` loop is executed faster than the equivalent `while` loop.

So do I have to settle for this kind of trade-off, or is my assumption above wrong, and there is no significant memory impact when iterating a large `range`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: My question is "does range consume memory", not "what is the difference between range and xrange". So **by definition**, these two questions cannot be a duplicate. The two answers might be, so you can mark them duplicate instead.

Comment: @khelwood: My question is "does range consume memory", not "what is the difference between range and xrange". So **by definition**, these two questions cannot be a duplicate. The two answers might be, so you can mark them duplicate instead.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: My question is "does range consume memory", not "what is the difference between range and xrange". So **by definition**, these two questions cannot be a duplicate. The two answers might be, so you can mark them duplicate instead.

Comment: *Clears Throat* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129146/how-do-i-create-a-for-loop-where-the-variables-value-is-equal-to-the-stop-value

Comment: The irony of doing exact same comment three times. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in python-2.x `range` will create the whole list.

But you don't necessarily need a `while` loop you can also use the lazy-`range`-alternative: `xrange`.

```
for i in xrange(1000000000):
    ...
```

Comment: Great, thanks. But wouldn't that ultimately affect performance in the same way that a `while` loop does?

Comment: @goodvibration: Probably `for i in xrange` will be slightly faster than `while`, but difference will be small. In general for short lists, `range` will be faster than `xrange` but use more memory. It would only be noticeably be faster if you have a situation where you get to re-use the list a lot, because `xrange` will always generate elements on the fly, whilst you can re-use the list from `range` multiple times, it is just a list. At some point the memory use will get to the point that `xrange` is faster regardless. And for *most* purposes the difference is small either way,

Comment: @goodvibration In my experience `xrange` will be faster than `range` and much faster than `while` for everything except short `range`s. There `range` is a bit faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!!!

Comment: @goodvibration I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/e739bc60a703d4b9eca6849a80022006) with my timings, you can experiment with that yourself if you like :)